# How to calculate $\nabla v^\top A x$ for a matrix A and fixed vector v?

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $v \in \mathbb{R}^m$ be fixed and $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ variable. For deriving the Lagrangian of a linear problem I have to calculate

$$\nabla_x v^\top A x$$

But I have troubles understanding how $\nabla$ behaves. We often speak of it as an operator, it is also commonly used like a vector, and I can't quite tell what arithmetic rules apply to it. Here is how I tried it using the linearity property I assume an operator must have:

$$\nabla_x v^\top A x = \sum_{j=1}^m v_j \nabla (Ax)_j$$

Now $(Ax)_j \in \mathbb{R}$, so depending on $x$ it is a function $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ to which I can apply the standard definition of the gradient

$$\sum_{j=1}^m v_j \nabla (Ax)_j
 =\sum_{j=1}^m v_j \pmatrix{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial A_{j,i} x_i} {\partial x_1} \\ \vdots \\ \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial A_{j,i} x_i}{\partial x_n}}
 = \sum_{j=1}^m v_j \pmatrix{\sum_{i=1}^n A_{j,i} \frac{\partial x_i} {\partial x_1} \\ \vdots \\ \sum_{i=1}^n A_{j,i} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_n}}
 = \sum_{j=1}^m v_j \sum_{i=1}^n A_{j,i} \pmatrix{ \frac{\partial x_i} {\partial x_1} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_n}}$$

where I used linearity again. Now for $k \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ we have  $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_k} = 1$ exactly when $i=k$ and $0$ otherwise.
So I should get

$$\sum_{j=1}^m v_j \sum_{i=1}^n A_{j,i} \pmatrix{ \frac{\partial x_i} {\partial x_1} \\ \vdots \\ \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_n}}
 = \sum_{j=1}^m v_j \sum_{i=1}^n A_{j,i} e_i $$

where $e_i$ is the $i$-th unit vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$. If I switch the sums I get

$$\sum_{j=1}^m v_j \sum_{i=1}^n A_{j,i} e_i = \sum_{i=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^m v_j A_{j,i}) e_i$$

which I can write as a vector-matrix product again

$$\sum_{i=1}^n (\sum_{j=1}^m v_j A_{j,i}) e_i = \sum_{i=1}^n (v^\top A)_i e_i = (v^\top A)^\top = A^\top v $$

Is this the correct result? And if so, is there a shorter way to do this with properties of the $\nabla$-operator I'm unaware of?

Comment: Let me get this straight: you mean $\nabla(\boldsymbol v^\intercal\mathbf{A}\boldsymbol x)$ and not $(\nabla \boldsymbol v)^\intercal \mathbf{A}\boldsymbol x$ ?

Comment: And also, for partial derivatives use `\partial`, not `\delta`.

Comment: The result looks right to me, I referenced [The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf) Eqns. 96 & 97.  It would be nice to see what "shortcut" property could be used.

Comment: @K.defaoite yeah exactly. Thanks for the edit, will use '\partial' in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is very easy with index notation. Assume we are working in the standard basis.

$$(\nabla v^\intercal A x)_k=\partial_k(v^\intercal Ax) \\ =\partial_k(v_iA^i_jx^j)$$
Since $\boldsymbol v, \mathbf{A}$ are constant, we can factor out the scalar multiples $v^i, A^i_j$ to get
$$=v_iA^i_j\partial_k x^j$$
And of course,
$$\partial_kx^j=\delta^j_k$$
Therefore
$$v_iA^i_j\partial_kx^j=v_iA^i_j\delta^j_k=v_iA^i_k$$
So
$$(\nabla v^\intercal Ax)_k=v_iA^i_k$$
In coordinate free form this means
$$\nabla(\boldsymbol v^\intercal \mathbf{A}\boldsymbol x)=\boldsymbol v^\intercal\mathbf{A}$$
This is basically just the derivative of a linear function of $\boldsymbol x$.

Comment: I have some trouble understanding the equation $\partial_k (v^\top Ax) = \partial_k ( v_i A_j^i x^j )$. Could you explain that notation?

Something must be off in so far as your result is a row vector, not a column vector, but maybe that is just a typo.

Comment: @lpnorm In higher mathematics, $\nabla$ is a row vector, not a column vector. That's because it transforms contravariantly, not covariantly.

Comment: And what is that 'higher mathematics' you are speaking of? I don't mean to be rude but that sounds a bit arrogant. I'm in my mathematics major and so far nobody referenced the 'higher mathematics' to me. It makes sense that $\nabla f(x)$ is a column vector when it represents the gradient since for every specific $x$ it is in the domain of $f$.  I mentioned that $\nabla$ does not yet make much sense to me so if you know what 'type' of operator it represents and how it is understood/studied please add that to the reply.

Comment: @lpnorm In the simplest terms possible, the thing that I have computed is just the transpose of the thing you are used to. So just transpose my result. If you are more interested why I define it as a row vector, google "covariant derivative". The gradient is actually a index-raised version of the del operator, i.e $\operatorname{grad}=\nabla^\sharp$. To learn about what this means google "musical ismorphism" and "index gymnastics".

Comment: Thanks for those leads. They are quite helpful!
If you add a short explanation w.r.t. the notation you use to your answer I would accept it. I don't think it is very common outside of differential geometry.